# Returning an object of same return type gives a syntax error

Tags: java, lambda

I have two functions. They are as follows,

```
public Post findById(Long id){
    for (Post thePost : ALL_POSTS) {
        if(thePost.getId()==id){
            return thePost;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public Post findById_Two(Long id) {
    ALL_POSTS.forEach((thePost) -> {
        if(thePost.getId()==id){
            System.out.println(thePost.getId()==id);
            return thePost;
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, both functions have a return Type of class `Post` and returns an object of the same class after a simple check. The first function works fine without any errors while the second function gives me an `Unexpected return value` error while trying to return `thePost`.

Can you please let me know what is causing this error and where did I go wrong?

Comment: Note: Learn to be specific about communicating messages. You should not be getting a _syntax_ error; the syntax is correct. The error comes at a later stage in the compilation process.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Sure. Got it. Thanks for the help and feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using `return` from inside a lambda expression returns *from the lambda*. Your `forEach` expects a `Consumer<Post>`, which is normally `void`. It's okay to provide a lambda that does return a value where void is expected (the value is just ignored), but you are returning a value only where you have a match—and then you'd proceed to `return null` unconditionally.

If you're going to use lambdas, use lambda style:

```java
public Post findById_streams(Long id) {
  return ALL_POSTS.stream()
    .filter(post -> id.equals(post.getId()))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
}
```

(Note also that you have a bug in comparing `Long` by `==`; the code above handles that.)